# How do I change text on top links

Tags: magento2, theme, xml, toplinks

I am designing a theme in Magento 2 using blank theme as parent theme. I would like to change text on some of the the top links like this:

From `"Compare Products 1 items"` into `"Compare (1)"`

From `"My Wish List 1 items"` into `"Wish List (1)"`

From `"My Cart 1 items"` into `"Cart (1)"`

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

In your theme create i18n/en_US.csv with the following

```
"Compare Products %1 items","Compare (%1)"
"My Wish List %1 items","Wish List (%1)"
"My Cart %1 items","Cart (%1)"
```

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/i18n

Comment: This is the best solution to use because you can make the change for individual languages without the need for writing a plugin, overriding code files or worse, editing core files. Translation files should always be used where possible!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it though plugin also

write plugin for getLabel() function for below class

```
vendor\magento\module-wishlist\Block\Link.php
vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\Link.php
```